# Find command in for loop

Tags: bash, for-loop

I have bash script that intents to find all files older then "X" minutes and to redirect the output into a file. The logic is a have a for loop and i want to do a find through all files, but for some reason it prints and redirect in the output file just the file from the last directory(TESTS[3]="/tmp/test/"). So i want all the files from the directories to be redirected there. Thank you for the help :D

Here is the sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x






if [ ! -d $TEST ]
then
    echo "The directory does not exist (${TEST})!"
    echo "Aborted."
    exit 1
fi


TESTS[0]="/tmp/t1/"
TESTS[1]="/tmp/t2/"
TESTS[2]="/tmp/t3/"
TESTS[3]="/tmp/test/"

for TEST in "${TESTS[@]}"
do
find $TEST -type f -mmin +1 -exec ls -ltrah {}  \; > /root/alex/out
done
```

Comment: Great. So there's something wrong with the script?

Comment: hello, idk if there is smth wrong or not.  It just don`t redirect the files from TESTS[0] , TESTS[1] , TESTS[2] ,  just from TESTS[3]  and i want from all of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `>` inside the loop to redirect the output of the latest command to the file each time, *overwriting* the previous contents of the file. If you used `>>` it would open the file in "append" mode each time instead, but...

A better way to fix your issue would be by moving the redirection to outside the loop:

```
done > /root/alex/out
```

And an even better way than that would be to avoid a loop entirely and just use:

```
find "${TESTS[@]}" -type f -mmin +1 -exec ls -ltrah {}  \; > /root/alex/out
```

Since `find` accepts multiple paths.

I think you can use `{} +` instead of `{} \;` to call the minimum number of `ls` required to process all arguments, and you might want to check `-printf` in `man find` because you can probably get a similar output using built-in format specifiers without calling `ls` at all.